# Pytorch precomputing part of a loss function

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to use pytorch to calculate a complex function but still require the gradient of the output as a function of the inputs. For example:

```
a=torch.tensor([1,2,3], dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True)
b=torch.tensor([3,2,1], dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True)
v=torch.tensor([0.2], dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True)

# here precalc represents some (fairly expensive) sequence of operations
precalc = a.dot(b)+a*b+a*a+b*b

def calc(precalc, v):
    z=torch.randn(3,1000)
    batch=v*precalc.matmul(z)
    return torch.relu(batch).mean()
```

So the precalc tensor is a fixed function of a and b (but expensive to compute).

When I call calc for the first time as `x=calc(precalc, v)` and then `x.backward()`, I get the correct gradients for a,b and v. However, if I call calc a second time, i.e. `x2=calc(precalc, v)` and then `x2.backward()`, I get the pytorch error that I'm going backward through the graph a second time and I should retain the graph.

I would ideally like to free the graph as precalc is expensive to compute but small in memory and the calc itself is easier to compute but will use a lot of memory.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: If the variables a, b, and v will stay fixed until you need to compute `precalc` again, then you can simply call `.backward()` on the sum of the returns of `calc` instead of doing it every time. This way, `precalc` will be computed only once.

Comment: I tried that and then I noticed (via nvidia-smi) that the GPU memory kept increasing for each iteration of calc. My real calc function is just running a MC simulation on the variables that have been precalculated (only needing fresh gaussian vars) . The only reason I ran backward inside each calc was to keep the memory footprint small.